# confusion about files end with .thtml and what exactly are they

Tags: html, frontend

I was going over my company's code base, and I saw some file format I have never seen before. They are all ended with `.thtml` .
What exactly is the `.thtml`? I was told it is for template files, and every time I view it in vscode I need to choose a language at bottom right corner of the IDE (default was plain text). What is the use of template file in web development? Are they the substitutes of `.html` files?

Answer (score 2):

HTML templates are HTML files enriched with variables, macros or other logic. They need to be preprocessed to ordinary HTML files before they can be viewed in a broswer. HTML templates are very useful when you want to create a lot of static HTML files sharing the same structure but with different contents.

There are several HTML templating engines out there, of which one happens to be named exactly **[thtml](https://github.com/leonelquinteros/thtml)**. (Of course this does not guarantee that it is the one your company uses.)